# Running Visual Studio under Parallels get error with Create on Strongly Typed View

Tags: visual-studio-2010, parallels

I Get the below error when using Visual Studio to add a strongly typed view. Visual Studio is running via Parallels and the code is store on the Mac (I assume the problem is down to this) - Anyone experienced this?

[image]

```
---------------------------
The templates had the following 1 error(s) when running:
---------------------------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML\Empty.tt(-1,-1) : error : An Exception was thrown while running the transformation code. The process cannot continue.  The following Exception was thrown:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Coyote.Logic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'Coyote.Logic, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'



Server stack trace: 

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)

   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)



Exception rethrown at [0]: 

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.RunTransformation(TemplateProcessingSession session, String source, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, String& result)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.CompileAndRunCode(String generatorCode, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, TemplateProcessingSession session)



WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.

To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].




---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: If you press Ctrl+C while the error message is shown, you can copy the contents to the clipboard. That would be helpful to have in the question.